# Towards a canonical homework question

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises, policy

> Note that the site's current policy on homework questions is found at
>
> **[How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)**
>
> which will always have the current version of the policy.

---

Many communities must deal with this question sooner or later, might as well get the ball rolling.

- How should we deal with homework questions?

I find that the Mathematics.StackExchange site is handling things well. Here are some links to their deliberations on these matters. As a frequent user of that site, I must say that we have been fairly successful of handling these questions well: both supportive, but not too helpful to be destructive to the questioner.

[How to deal with HW questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/106/)

[More policy about HW questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/)

[How to not give complete solutions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/415/)

[Homework tags.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/621/)

Update July 2014:

[Math.SE votes on homework tag.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14981/11127)

[Result of voting.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16425/11127)

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with your answer on math meta (your first link.)

Comment: Good job linking to Mathematics, a moderator there linked me to one of those when I asked the same.

Answer (score 8):

Most people have enough of a sense of the concept of "fair play" that I'd like to think this would be a non-issue. Unfortunately, it's almost certainly going to come up, and we don't want to deter people from legitimately using this site.

Cribbing from [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow) - on which the Mathematics.StackExchange site builds:

There are two principles involved:

1. **It is okay to ask about homework**. For one, it would be impossible to stop it all even if we wanted to. Stack Overflow exists to help programmers learn and provide a standard repository for programming problems, both simple and complex, and this includes helping students.
2. **Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest**. Therefore you might choose to treat homework questions differently than other questions.

I agree that it'll be nigh-impossible to determine in advance which are homework questions 100% of the time. On the other hand, there will be those questions are going to stick out like a sore thumb as obvious homework. I don't think we want to get in the habit of providing homework answers directly, as that directly violates principle 2.

I don't think it's wrong to inquire if a question is a homework or class-related question in the comments. If it is, the questioner ought to be willing to accept help in a form similar to what they might get from a reasonably accommodating professor or TA, and it should be our job to do that.

Ideally, if we could get people with homework questions to **voluntarily** tag their questions appropriately, then everyone would benefit. Maybe this ought to be in our FAQs or guidelines somewhere.

Comment: I agree with most everything you say here.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is (as of August 2014) pretty outdated. This site's official homework policy is found at

> **[How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)**

For recent discussions about possible changes to this policy, see [Bite-sizing homework](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/bite-sizing-homework), [Why don't we just ban homework altogether?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/why-dont-we-just-ban-homework-altogether), [Banning homework: vote and documentation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5179/banning-homework-vote-and-documentation), [Does banning homework do long-term harm for only short-term gain?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/does-banning-homework-do-long-term-harm-for-only-short-term-gain), [A week of community closing: what should be disallowed homework?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/a-week-of-community-closing-what-should-be-disallowed-homework), [Can we please stop applying the homework tag (and policy) to very advanced questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5372/2751), and links therein.

Note, also, that as of July 30 2014, math.SE has [banned the (homework) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what), though homework questions are [apparently still on-topic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: This upvoted thread should also be kept in mind http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5372/2751 ...

Comment: @Dilaton edited it in. I'd be curious to know the reason for the downvote - I was hoping for this to float to the top, as this is merely a signpost to the state of the discussion ~4 years later, including what is likely to remain as [the *actual* canonical homework question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) (in the sense that changes in policy will most likely be reflected in edits to that instead of new posts).