# Off-topic question

Tags: support, scope, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises, close-reasons

I posted [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168649/) on Phys.SE and the question was closed as off-topic. As a matter of fact I did a mistake when selecting the tags, since I used the homework tag. When I realized that I did a mistake I modified the tag, however the question was closed as off-topic. I really would get an answer to my question, so have I to post the question once more ? Why it wasn't enough to modify the tags?

Comment: Since you have been working on the question over the last day I think I should mention that edited, closed question go into the review queues from high rep users to look at and consider for re-opening. But we have only so many users at that level so review can take a while. Alas you don't get any feedback if they decide against re-opening.

Comment: First of all thank you for information. I'll check myself, this is not an issue. There is no rush, I do physics and math in my spare time. My goal is just to understand.

Comment: For the record, the determination of whether a question is on topic is based on the body, not the tags or title. So changing the tags won't make an off-topic question on topic.

Comment: Hi David, than you for your answer. Now it's crystal clear.

Answer (score 4):

Your question appears to [fit within the definition of homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5959/520) used on the site, the tag should be applied and the question (in its current state) should be closed.

If you look at the question I've just linked you to and at [the one linked in the close message](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/), you may find some guidance for render your question into a form suitable for the site.

Given the sophistication of the work you exhibit I would be unsurprised if you were able to retool to a question we'd accept.