# Why is this question being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes, voting

[Can a harmonic oscillator have different maximum potential and kinetic energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/545256/)

What should I do to make it upvoted? Was I not clear in the question or what is it? I haven't particularly asked help in calculations or doing questions just as to why one line of thinking is wrong...

Comment: I'm not sure it is useful to ask questions on meta that are just asking for the reason for downvotes. If the actual downvoters had wished to explain themselves to you, they'd have left a comment, and everyone else is just speculating.

Comment: On an average I see posts get +2 or -2 votes, Now I supposed that this reflective of the average consensus of the people who click 'vote'. I made this question to ask if there is something blatant that I'm not seeing which is wrong (according to group of people who vote on stuff) with my problem because I am unable to see it.

Yeah sorry if this all sounded a bit contrived

Comment: I think it's reasonable to ask this, you just have to live with an uncertain answer. People who didn't downvote can still identify issues that _might_ have caused others to downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe certain users view it as a kind of "check my work problem" (I view it this way, hence my vote to close). You are asking others to check the work you are doing and compare it to / check the work done by someone else as well.

Also some users are very quick to down vote a question that involves a simple mechanics exercise thinking that a user is just looking for homework help.

Note that I'm not saying that either of these things are your intention, just giving a possible explanation for the down votes.

Answer (score 8):

This is a typical check-my-work problem that IMO is not terribly interesting beyond answering a specific question by the OP.

I didn’t downvote the question, but I did vote to close: there’s nothing intrinsically wrong with the question but I do think if people ask too many questions of this type the site will become a homework help site and will lose its appeal.

Comment: But *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635954/what-is-the-angle-x)* is thriving...? I have never seen a close vote (they exist of course) or a comment questioning whether an obvious homework question should be closed on that site.

Comment: Okay maybe I phrased it wrong should I have put it like I have no ideas on this matter already can someone tell me a new idea for it? 

I think I phrased it like " I have this idea about the matter, is this not always the case or is something wrong with the solution key?"

Comment: @DDD4C4U You’re missing the point I think. This type of *specific* non-conceptual question is not one that this community has chosen to focus on.  Simply stating “I don’t know how to do this help me” will not change the the fact it remains of limited interest to the community at large.

Comment: How is not conceptual? I asked if a specific idea is correct or wrong. It was more clarification question

Comment: see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10939/36194 for instance.  Asking if a specific idea is right or wring is “check-my-work” and out of bounds.