# How frequently can I ask questions on one site and in one tag?

Tags: support, questions, policy

When I'm studying physics, I get questions I can't answer constantly. I usually leave a question after I try to solve it 2 or 3 times and don't get anywhere. I return to it again after a week or two and that sometimes helps, but I still have lots of them unclear ones.

So that's why I joined this site, but I'm a bit worried about asking too many questions. Seeing there are about 230 000 questions on physics.stackexchange and that a new one is asked about three times per hour, I wouldn't wish mine completely overflowing all others, especially because I'll mostly be asking in a few certain tags.

Is there a limit and to which extent can I ask in the same tag without abusing the site and other members?

Comment: Please pay particular attention to our on-topic policy (https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Asking for the solutions to exercises or homework is off topic here.

Comment: Maybe start by getting the punctuation right.

Answer (score 11):

There is no limit but you would be *very* prolific if you could ask more than one good question per week, although initially you might have a backlog of good questions.

It is NOT easy to ask good questions because the site is fairly mature and already has a large repository of questions on a large number of topics, so your question might quickly be closed as duplicate.

In addition, "check-my-work"-type questions, or assignment-like questions, are also rapidly closed as this is not a site for help with homework or derivations (see [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/36194)). The good questions are conceptual, as discussed
[here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10938/36194), and experience has shown that most users struggle to frequently ask good conceptual questions.

If too many of your questions are closed or downvoted because they are not good, you may end up into a forced pause.

Comment: I have a [Data Explorer query which tracks prolific answerers and askers](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/840905/most-prolific-answerers-during-date-interval-mean-answer-score). In the month preceding 2023-12-17, this week's data dump cutoff, our most prolific askers averaged a question every three or five days, while our most prolific answerers averaged a little under one answer a day.

Comment: Right.  Basically we have two users with an average of more than 1 question per week, with the most prolific asker averaging 1.54 questions per week; there are 300k + users.  I suspect other users with a rush of questions eventually get banned or abandon the site because their questions are closed or heavily downvoted.