# I am not able to understand what should I do on this question to avoid it from being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, homework-and-exercises, down-votes

Please help me understanding about How I should improve my questions like this-

[How does torque operate? What will be going on with disc?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458606/184435)

from being downvoted?

1. I think I have given the specific difficulty How does the torque operate and which torque is it?
2. Shown my work.
3. Have given the full details as it is in the source. I think the question has all the details.
4. Its not a duplicate question.
5. I have maintained decency in the language.

Please help me in improving my question

---

> Edit--Now please the question I have edited it and please see if more can be done to make it a better question.

Comment: @Chair But why? I want to improve my questions. What should I do if I am not able to know what mistakes I am making in asking  the questions?

Comment: Read [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6705) and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938) for a start. If possible, try to remove the problem statement entirely and boil it down to individual concepts. Adding a picture to describe the situation might also be helpful.

Comment: @Blue Actually, when a question is inspired by a problem (such as from a homework assignment), we ask that people _do_ include the original problem as a blockquote, to provide context. But it's probably a useful rule of thumb that the question should still make sense even if the quote of the original problem were taken out.

Comment: I do not know why it’s been downvoted but as it stands now your question is broad and you’re just asking people to write a long lesson on this topic without knowing exactly what you do not understand.